# How can I test a CNG key for exchangeable?

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, x509certificate2, cng

I have taken a certificate:

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "CNGTestCert", false)[0];
```

and now I want to get the providertype parameter. But I cant do `x509.PrivateKey`.
In result of this I used `var key = x509.GetRSAPrivateKey();`. How can I get out of this `key` the ProviderType to decide the KeyNumber (looks like here: [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/icspasymmetricalgorithm.cs,39)). Or is there a easier way to test the private key for key function (key was created for signature or exchange)?

Comment: What is KeyNumber?

Comment: What does "exchangeable" mean?

Comment: It seems that `KeyNumber` stands for `KeySpec`. For CNG keys it is always 0fffffffff or -1. And CNG keys do not have `ProviderType` either. Exchangeable -- I can suspect, that it is whether the key is exportable or not?

Comment: @Crypt32 The Key should be tested for key function. Looking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.keynumber?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: As I said, for CNG keys, KeyNumber is always -1 and its meaning is undefined. CNG keys no longer use/specify `AT_EXCHANGE` or `AT_SIGNATURE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to check CNG certificate for exchangeable. If I read the private key of certificate by `var privateKey = (cngCert.GetRSAPrivateKey() as RSACng).Key;`, did I get the KeyUsage. The "KeyAgreement" flag marks the certificate for usage of secret agreement generation and key exchange.

```
var privateKey = (cngCert.GetRSAPrivateKey() as RSACng).Key;
        
        if(privateKey.KeyUsage.HasFlag(CngKeyUsages.KeyAgreement))
        {
            //is for KeyExchange 
        }
```